# How to get distance between two coordinates with Mapbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox

I am learning how to use the Mapbox API for my node app and I want to perform calculations on the backend like getting the distance between two coordinates.

How can I achieve this?, the Mapbox documentation doesn't make this clear...

Set-up the SDK

```
const mapboxSdk = require("mapbox")
let mapbox = new mapboxSdk(process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN)
```

// EXAMPLE OF WHAT I WANT TO DO

```
coordA = {lat : 33.968123, long: -118.419454}

coordB = {{lat : 33.997223, long: -117.929145}}

const distance = await mapbox.getDistance(coordA, coordB)

console.log(distance)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Mapbox recommends using the Turf.js library for this type of thing: [Turf.js Distance Function](https://turfjs.org/docs/#distance). However, the distance between two lat/long coords is a simple geometry problem that doesn't need any external APIs/libraries, and can be calculated from your coordinates using the [Haversine Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21623206/11963779) for implementations of the Haversine formula as a javascript function.